# Chart.js - tooltiptemplate with one decimal value in pie chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have implemented pie charts using chart.js. In that I need to display `tooltip` as percentage value with one decimal place.

I have tried so many ways but nothing seems to work.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 $.each(data,function(i,val){
            piedata.push({value:val.Count,color:val.color,label:val.name});
        });

        Chart.types.Pie.extend({
            name: "PieAlt",
            draw: function(){
                Chart.types.Pie.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
                drawSegmentValues(this)
            }
        });

        var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).PieAlt(piedata, {
            tooltipTemplate: "<%= (circumference / 6.283 * 100).toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?/)[0] %>%"
        });

        var radius = myPieChart.outerRadius;
```

`tooltipTemplate` does not take any format or function.

Please recommend a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toFixed` function.

```
(circumference / 6.283 * 100).toFixed(1)
```

Comment: toFixed will round up the value..but I want actual value with one decimal place alone..For ex:one slice of a pie's percentage is 51.534345% I want to display 51.5%